# How to create email as activity in salesforce using rest api

Tags: lightning, rest-api, lightning-web-components

I am new to salesforce.

In side contact, i can create new task, log a call and event using rest api. But how can i create email as contact activity using rest api??

EDIT:

Creating task directly from following URL.

Rest api URL: `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Task/post-task/try`

Request:

```
{
    "WhoId": "0032v00002rSX3lAAG",
    "Status": "In Progress",
    "Subject": "Test from API",
    "TaskSubtype": "Call"
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add your code to create task!

Comment: @Ayub, i have updated the question.

Comment: Use email message object for this, like: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/EmailMessage

Comment: I already did it. But it simply creates email message. I want it inside contact activity. How can i do that??

Comment: Yes, emailmessage is the object where it is stored. Make sure that you pass ToIds field as below:
String[] toIds = new String[]{'003B000000AxcEjIAJ'};

emailMessage.toIds = toIds;

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot.
But in documentation there is no parameter like toIds. Can you please tell me which documentation you follow??

Comment: Sure lmme add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email shown under activity is actually stored in Object "EmailMessage". So you need to create EmailMessage Record: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/EmailMessage/post-emailmessage. But note that, in order to associate this new EmailMessage record with Contact, you will have to pass ContactId as "ToIds" field; Here is salesforce article (look at bottom of this article): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm

```
String[] toIds = new String[]{'003B000000AxcEjIAJ'};
emailMessage.toIds = toIds;
```